# gnuplot using ``using`` to produce labels

Tags: layout, plot, gnuplot, percentage, errorbar

I have data in form

```
x y ymin ymax percentage
```

I'm plotting this

```
plot "file.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with yerrorbars [...]
```

Now how can I round the percentage to integers and place them as labels above the error bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
plot "file.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with yerrorbars, '' u 1:2:(sprintf("%d",$5)) w labels
```

Type `help labels` for more informationa about it